# How to perform operations after the shell complete the drag&drop in a COM Drag&Drop Handler?

Tags: winapi, com, windows-shell, shell-extensions

On Windows, I want to have a folder named *Automatic Folder*. When I drag and drop something in it, the folder rename itself *Folder 1* and a new empty *Automatic Folder* is created. Ending up with two folders:

1. *Folder 1* : containing the dragged and dropped files.
2. *Automatic Folder* : empty, ready for a new drag and drop in it.

To achieve this goal, I implemented the `IShellExtInit` and `IContextMenu` interfaces in a C++ DLL and I edited my registry to inform the shell to call my DLL when someone drag and drop something in a folder.
When my DLL is called, I rename the folder and create a new one. It works, but (as the Windows documentation point it out) this happens before the shell complete the drop operation. And when the shell finish the drop, it put the dragged and dropped files into the *Automatic Folder* while I expected the shell to put them into the *Folder 1*. (I hoped the shell identify folders by an ID that doesn't change on rename)

**My question**: Is there a way to end up with the files into the *Folder 1* ? Either by:

1. Telling the shell to call my DLL after the drop complete.
2. Telling the shell to execute the `SHFileOperationW` and `CreateDirectoryW` calls, I make to rename and create folders, later.
3. Redirecting the drag and drop targeted folder.
4. Any other solution (if possible, other than waiting 1 second hoping the shell finished before renaming the folder).

I tried:

1. Setting up the `FOF_WANTMAPPINGHANDLE` flag and giving a `HANDLETOMAPPINGS` during the `SHFileOperationW` call, hoping the shell will do some mapping.
2. Calling `SHChangeNotify` after the renamed, to notify a folder has been renamed.
3. Having the shell asked for an `IDropTarget` interface, (hoping it will open new doors) but it seems to be possible only when you drag and drop onto a file, not a folder.

I wish you a nice day :)

Comment: “*To achieve this goal, I implemented the IShellExtInit and IContextMenu interfaces*" - IContextMenu has nothing to do with Drop&Drop. Did you mean `IDropTarget` instead? [How to Create Drop Handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-create-drop-handlers). Also see [Handling Shell Data Transfer Scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/datascenarios)

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau for your comment. As said in the "I tried" part (point 3), yes I tried to implement `IDropTarget` but when I log the shell calls to my DLL, it doesn't ask for this inteface. Then I realise the documentation page you point out never use the words "Folder" or "Directory" and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/reg-shell-exts#handler-names) the table said the interface for a Drag-and-Drop handler is `IContextMenu`. I think a `IDropTarget` is only for files but I'm not sure, did you already succeed to make the shell asks for a `IDropTarget` for folders ?

Comment: Is there anyway you would consider a different solution to your underlying problem? Because this seems a pretty poor solution to any problem. Like perhaps you have a service monitor the folder and then do the work. After all, drag and drop isn't the only way to get objects into a directory, and is often a really really inconvenient way to do it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, the description of the issue doesn't explain all the context. The COM Object/DLL manage other tasks already and I would like to add this task to it. So I would prefer a solution close to what I ask. However, if no solution exist, yes I will probably do it another way but I dislike services that check periodicaly if something happend, call backs are cleaner. And this case is a great occasion for me to learn, so I would prefer a cleaner solution.

Comment: There's no way to determine the end of a drag & drop operation from an external point of view.

Comment: Why do you want to force the user to use drag and drop which may be very inconvenient. I don't think drag and drop should ever be the only way to do things. Also, from the user's perspective, why would drag and drop be treated differently from pasting?

Comment: @SimonMourier, thank you for you answer, Is there a way to tell the shell to interupt / cancel the drag & drop operation (from the drag & drop handler) so I can do it myself or call another drag & drop onto the right folder ?

Comment: @Pauly - drag & drop operations are done by the Shell, from a source to a target. Source and target don't even know each other, they're just ends of the communication (represented by a common data object containing memory blocks and/or streams). And there's no software component in the middle except the Shell itself. There's no public API exposed to change this.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, you are right, the usecase as described in the question is not perfectly design and doesn't handle all the possible cases. I kept it simple. So my question is not about how to improve it but it's about how to do it this way. I know how to do it with a program that periodicaly check the content of the folder but I don't like this solution. Behind that, there are questions about : performances for million of folders ? What if the access to the folder is slow, encrypted, not always possible ? ... If you have an idea that doesn't involve to check periodicaly the folder, I'm in :)

Comment: @SimonMourier Ok, thank for the answer. I will find another way then

Comment: @Pauly I would either write a monitor service, like David suggested, or else write a custom Shell Namespace Extension instead of using a plain filesystem folder.

Comment: *"If you have an idea that doesn't involve to check periodicaly the folder, I'm in"* - Like [`ReadDirectoryChangesW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-readdirectorychangesw)?

Comment: @IInspectable, thank you for this new potential solution. I'm just afraid the `ReadDirectoryChangesW` will trigger as soon as something change. If the user drag and drop 5 files, I guess it will trigger after the first file is moved/copied (and if I rename the folder at this instant I will have the same initial issue with the 4 others files) and I have no way to know when the drag and drop is finished. I will still do some tests with this method to see what is possible to do. Thanks.

Comment: @IInspectable, well, I know the number of files the drag and drop contain in the `IShellExtInit::Initialize` so I probably could count. Thank, I will try.

Comment: @IInspectable, If the drag and drop is interupted (error on some files or canceled by the user) the count is not possible anymore... but it was a good try :)